# Why does bash and zsh evaluate [-1] as 1?

Tags: bash, shell

I've noticed this surprising behavior and can not quite understand what's going on:

```
$ bash -c 'echo [-1]'
1

$ zsh -c 'echo [-1]'
1
```

It seems like the command parser tries to evaluate an expression:

```
$ echo [1,2,3]
1
$ echo [123-33]
1
```

Because if the expression is quoted, or indicate that a bracket is just a bracket, then the strange evaluation is omitted.

```
$ echo \[123-33]
[123-33]

$ echo [123-33\]
[123-33]

$ echo '[123-33]'
[123-33]
```

While looking for clues, I found this quote:

https://github.com/mvdan/sh

> Caveats
>
> When indexing Bash associative arrays, always use quotes. The static parser will otherwise have to assume that the index is an arithmetic expression.
>
> ```
> $ echo '${array[spaced string]}' | shfmt
> 1:16: not a valid arithmetic operator: string
> $ echo '${array[dash-string]}' | shfmt
> ${array[dash - string]}
> ```

Not sure what to make of it, because there is no array to speak of in the context of `echo [1-1]`

This could of course be caused by something in my own environment, but when I check, it does not seem to be:

```
$ env -i HOME=$(mktemp -d) bash --noprofile --norc
bash-5.1$ echo [1-1]
1

$ env -i HOME=$(mktemp -d) /bin/bash-4.4  --noprofile --norc
bash-4.4-4.4$ echo [1-1]
1
```

But then again, on a ubuntu box I get a different result:

```
$ bash --version | sed 1q; echo [1-1]
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
[1-1]
```

Disabling all options does not change this behavior.

```
for i in `shopt | awk '/on$/ { print $1}'`; do shopt -u $i;done
```

---

Do you have any idea what's causing this bracket expression to be evaluated and why is the result 1?

Comment: **You have a file named `1` in your current directory** only on the first box. `[anything]` as a command argument is a filename pattern (aka 'glob') that matches any and all filename(s) which is one of the characters in the brackets (except if you have x-y within the brackets, that matches any character in the _range_ x to y) and the program, here `echo`, is run with the resulting filename(s) as argument(s) not the pattern. If the pattern does NOT match, by default the program is run with the pattern as an argument in bash (but not in zsh, which you don't show); options can change this.

Comment: As you observed if the argument is quoted it isn't treated as a pattern, and is passed to the program. See the manual https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only happens if you have a file named `1` in the current directory.

```
$ bash -c 'echo [-1]'
[-1]
$ touch 1
$ bash -c 'echo [-1]'
1
$ rm 1
$ bash -c 'echo [-1]'
[-1]
```

Why? The shell does globbing on `[-1]` which matches files called `-` or `1`. So if a file with such a one-character name exists, the glob matches and you get the filename. If no such file exists, the glob remains unchanged.

PS: It also works with `-`:

```
$ touch ./-
$ bash -c 'echo [-1]'
-
```

Comment: yes. you are onto something. how about: `$ echo [1231.3-89.1]`?

Comment: `touch 3 ; echo [1231.3-89.1];`  prints 3. that's so idiotic. why does the single digit 3 appear in that range?

Comment: nvm. i get it now. `touch 3 ; echo [1261.8-89.1]; => [1261.8-89.1]` the characters are just plain characters, I guess i was confused by range expansion ({22..15}) or something.